# AppCompatActivity instead of Activity or FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, appcompatactivity

I've been trying out implementing navigation in android through navigation drawers and swipe views with tabs.
I've followed Google's developer tutorials ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)) and for both situations I could never get my code to work unless I changed Activity or FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity and applied other changes in the action bars code, for instance change getActionBar to getSupportActionBar so I don't get NPE.

Now the questions:

1- Why do I need to make these changes when I'm following official tutorials that should work the way they are?

2 - Is AppCompatActivity correct to use in these cases or is there a better way to do the same thing?

3 - Are these situations related to the min sdk and target sdk I chose? My min sdk is 14 and my target sdk is 22. Should I try to lower the target sdk?

4 - Are these situations related to the style/theme of my application? It's android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > .

Some insight on this subject is appreciated so thank you in advance.

Edit: Another thing I noticed is that I always need to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar instead of android.app.ActionBar so I don't get NPE, even though my min sdk is higher than API 11.

Edit2: I noticed some contradiction in the developers' guides. Because I want to use ActionBar, I need to get my imports right. Following [this link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html), it's recommended that I include v7 appcompat libraries, but following [this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) I need to import android.app.ActionBar because my min sdk is higher than 11. Like I said before, using android.app.ActionBar produces NPE, so what should I do?

Comment: You may want to inspect sources of this sample project: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Although the sources have code that I can check, they still don't answer my questions. Why do I have to use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity or FragmentActivity like in the Google Developer tutorials?

Comment: You are implementing it the old way. Look at @MarcinOrlowski 's link. 1. Official tutorials are outdated. 2. Yes. 3. No. 4. Use the `Toolbar`.